# Simple resources database

Tags: database, database-design

I have a small database with several hundred resources of varying types (medical, education and research, for example).  Each resource will need to be identified by its region.  Some of the resources serve multiple regions.  I need to be able to define each resource by its type, and it's region.

Since one region will have many resources, and one resource can serve many counties I figure I should have a junction table between them, right?

My question is, should I have a junction / linking table for each resource type?  Should I have a table of education_resources, regions and link them with a junction table education_regions? And do the same thing for the rest of the categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep columns common to all resources in the `Resource` table. Sub-type tables have only columns specific to each one.

[image]

Comment: Uh, looks like image server is down.

Comment: i'm not exactly sure i understand the symbols in this schema.  Does this mean I should have all of the resources listed in one, large table?  Then have a foreign key to the Resource table that corresponds to each resource type?  So, in essence, each resource type should only have a copy of the primary key of the resource table, correct?

Comment: @dzilla; correct. This is supertype-subtype model. Each sub-type contains only columns specific to it; all common columns are in the `Resource` table. `ResourceType` is a discriminator column like ('M', 'E', 'R').

Comment: @dzilla; see some more similar  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A196713+subtype

Comment: this is an interesting take and not at all how i would've tackled it.  what are the advantages to having the database set up this way?  what are the disadvantages?  while i'm not new to RBDs i'm not expert.  and i haven't ran across the supertype/subtype nomenclature before.

Comment: @dzilla, well it is fairly common. The supertype table keeps relationships with all other entities. If you add a new sub-type, relationship with `Region` does not change. Disadvantage is if you have many sub-types  -- each one has its own table.

Comment: what would be the disadvantages of designing it in my proposed method? the one with a junction table to resolve the many-to-many relationships?

Answer (score 1):

Creating tables with names like education_resources and medical_resources may make it difficult for you to extend your database if and when you add additional resource types. Instead you could have tables as:

```
Resource_Type (resource_type_id, resource_type_name)
Resource_Region (resource_region_id, resource_region_name)
Resource_counties (resource_county_id, resource_county_name)
Resources (resource_id, resource_type_id,...)
Resource_Region_Map (resource_region_id, resource_id)
Resource_County_Map (resource_county_id, resource_id)
```

Will this work for you, or will it make things more complicated?

Comment: I think that will make things a little more complicated.